# Does mediaResponse really support array of mediaObject?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

As the [document](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/MediaResponse) says, MediaResponse contains mediaObjects property, and mediaObjects is array of mediaObject, but when I tried to put multiple mediaObjects, I got this error:

> MalformedResponse at
>   expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/MediaResponse).media_response:
>   Only 1 media_object is allowed. First media_object will be used while
>   rest will be filtered.

Then what is the point of having an array of mediaObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several places in the protocol that contain an array where only one object is permitted in the array. One assumes that the designers wanted to make it expandable in the future without having to add special casing.

In this case, it sorta makes sense - right now we can only send one media object as part of the reply. It might be reasonable that, in the future, we could send one or more without having to come back to our webhook.

Comment: That makes sense. I just want to make sure I am not doing something wrong.